# TStringList problem with values at index

Tags: delphi, loops, tstringlist

So I have several summary files that I want to read and get the values from.

I am doing the following:

```
OutputSummary := TStringList.Create;
for idx := 0 to 82 do
  OutputSummary.Insert(idx, '');
```

to initialize the values I'm using

then, I have a loop:

```
for idx := 0 to SummaryFiles.Count - 1 do
  begin
    AssignFile(finp, SummaryFiles[idx]);
    ReSet(finp);

    for ndx := 0 to 5 do
      ReadLn(finp, buff);

    for ndx := 0 to 82 do   
      begin
        ReadLn(finp, buff);
        temp := GetToken(buff, ' ');
        buff := GetRemains(buff, '|');
        temp := GetToken(buff, '|');
        valuestring := OutputSummary[ndx] + delimiter + temp;
        OutputSummary.Insert(ndx, valuestring);

      end;

    CloseFile(finp);

end;
```

The first 0 to 5 loop skips the lines I don't want to read, and the 0 to 82 reads lines that look like

```
1. Initial Wait List|1770
```

So I was debugging the program to see how it works with just 2 SummaryFiles.

The first time through, it works perfectly. The line is read correctly, I get the value and when I insert valuestring, it looks like ",1770" (for example), and I can also highlight OutputSummary[ndx] after the insert command and see that the value was inserted correctly.

Then I open the second file, which also works fine until the line

```
valuestring := OutputSummary[ndx] + delimiter + temp;
```

the first time, OutputSummary[0] is correct and the correct line is added.

However, OutputSummary[1] through OutputSummary[82] is the same as OutputSummary[0]! This makes no sense since when I was first adding those values, I could see that OutputSummary[1] through 82 were unique and correct.

Can anyone see a problem? Is it a debugger error? Am I just missing something obvious that I don't see?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to create a table of some sort, with one column per input file and one row per line in the file, with the columns separated by the `delimiter`. If so, calling `.Insert` on the string list isn't going to quite work right, since you'll end up inserting `83 * SummaryFiles.Count` rows.

Instead of the `Insert` call, you need something like this:

```
if OutputSummary.count > ndx then
  OutputSummary[ndx] := valuestring
else OutputSummary.Add(valuestring);
```

See if that helps.

Also, you might want to consider replacing the "magic number" 82 with a meaningful constant, like `const LINES_TO_READ = 82`. That makes it easier to read the code and understand what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I think I originally had it this way but it gave me problems before I initialized the values, and I never changed it back.